# Display asp:ValidationSummary messages in other languages (Hebrew)

Tags: asp.net, validation, authentication

How can I display the asp:ValidationSummary messages in Hebrew?
Should I override it or is there a parameter to fiddle with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your comments I figured out, that the message was coming from `<asp:Login>` control on your page.

You can try to create new control class, inherit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login` and override `FailureText` property to match your language. Then use your custom control on ASPX page instead of standard Login control.

*EDIT:* No, wait... this is silly, too much work.
Login control does not have ID set. Add `ID="login"` to control, and then in code-behind, in `Page_Load` I'd add this:

```
this.login.FailureText = //assign your message (eg. pull it from resource files if you want to work in several languages)
```

Comment: Thanks, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your ValidationSummary will display a summary of all validation errors inline on a Web page, in a message box, or both. So each of your validators should have `Summary` property. You can set custom message for this property, in any language you want.

You can also play with validators and languages. For example create resource files, and in `Page_Load()` set summary message in certain language based on user's language.

Comment: I have changed the `ErrorMessage` parameter of each of the `asp:RequiredFieldValidator`, still the `asp:ValidationSummary` display other error messages. Where are those messages reside?

Comment: Seems like the messages I cannot chages are from `asp:Literal`. Can I change those?

Comment: Can you provide little bit of code? What messages are you seeing?

Comment: i'm using the VS 2010 template for Account management. The message `User name is required` is translated. The message I cannot translate is: `Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again`. Is it not coming from my project?

Comment: This is not from validators that you have on your page. Page validation was successful, but that comes from `asp:Login` control. And the property You are looking for is `FailureText`. Similar problem was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894885/new-asp-net-web-application-has-a-login-button-that-does-something-but-where

Answer (score 0):

move your validation summary messages to resource file.
convert your resource file to Hebrew
change the default resource file loaded to this file
thats it.